# How to obtain maps with regions and subregions

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

My problem: I want to obtain a map from a given country with subregions in r.

So far: For example `map` package provides `counties` map which database produces a map of the counties of the United States mainland generated from US Department of the Census data. Or for example `italy` map which provides subregions, such as in a pair of lines of code is possible to plot it:

```
it <- ggplot2::map_data("italy")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(it, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  coord_fixed()
```

I would like to obtain same maps for another countries but unfortunately I think that `maps` package only provides this information for USA, Italy and France. Is there a package which provides such information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the @alistaire's comment:

```r
library("rnaturalearth")
library("ggplot2")
spain <- ne_states(country = "spain", returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(data = spain) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

As proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659288/7654451) regions can be obtained just using `group_by` and `summarise`:

```r
spain %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  summarise() %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: How can you get those islands closer Spain? (left bottom)

Comment: Mmm I remember there are some packages that allow this kind of things. But rnaturalearth is not one of them...

Comment: How to save the sf file, "spain"?

Comment: @Masoud you can save it as a regular ggplot in png, jpg or another image format