# Make a map with a group of subregions with geom_sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I want to make a map only with the external borders by groups of subregions. Bellow are plotted all the subregions and I want to make a map but only with the external borders of the regions which are in `region` column in the `spain` object. I have tried with several `aes` like `fill` and `group` or even grouping by before plotting it but can't find a proper way:

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)

spain <- ne_states(country = "spain", returnclass = "sf")

spain %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Just to clarify regions are a group of printed shapes in the map above:

```r
spain %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = region)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: You can group the data and use `st_union`

Comment: As proposed bellow `summarise` did the work.  Thanks @camille for the support by second time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `group_by` and `st_union` are options:

```
spain %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  summarise() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = region)) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Comment: Use `summarise` in this case is something that I would never imagine... but somehow it works! Thanks @astrofunkswag !